# How to develop a map with layers in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have two shapefiles and two rasters. I need to develop a map in GeoServer (ver. 2.0.2) with those 4 elements. They should be like layers which I can turn on or off. I added them on GeoServer like .shp files and WorldImage file. I edited styles of shp files in uDig. When I click on Layer Preview I see those 4 elements, but I can see every element separately. I want to develop map which will have all 4 elements like layers. What is the next step to develop that kind of a map?

Also, can you give me some links on tutorials about GeoServer, other than those on official site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend working through lessons 7 & 8 of my [Web Mapping Course](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/). Lesson 8 will answer your question about building a client using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org).