# How to publish my map from geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geojson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop a map with layers in Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10046/how-to-develop-a-map-with-layers-in-geoserver)

I'm trying to create a simple map for my city. I have a shape file my city, but I can't create on the web.

I tried to take from geoserver to use geojson format but I didn't. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Try using, UDIG or OpenJump.

it provides facility to load and edit your shapefiles and export as a image file.